# Intellisense is not working when i created component with createRemoteVueComponent

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, shopify

i am using @remote-ui/vue package
const RemoteButton = createRemoteVueComponent<'Button', {onPress(): void}>(
'Button',
); //intellisense for onPress does not work
const RemoteButton = createRemoteReactComponent<'Button', {onPress(): void}>(
'Button',
);// intellisense for onPress works

intellisense in vue js is not working but in react works
i am expecting it should work as it is working with react and i am also using jsx in vue but why it is not working.